# How to view missing variables/methods in Intellij Groovy inspection reports

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I am trying to figure out how I can get Intellij to reprot bad these issues in inspection reporting.  This example I threw together shows 4 separate issues that do not get caught in anyway during inspection and I have all inspection settings turned on.

I understand the idea about the nature of Groovy and run-time vs compile-time errors.  The issue I see though is that IntelliJ knows there is something possibly wrong here because the IDE underlines and shades it.  So since it is aware and has a consistent messaging built-in regarding this type of potential issue, there should be a way to report on it even if it's just a weak warning or something.  Instead I am given a clean inspection.  Am I missing something in the configurations, is there a way to get this type of issue flagged?

[image: Intellij inspection issues]

I am using `IntelliJ 2020.2` if that matters.

Edit:
To clarify what I am looking for is you can see in the picture the IDE is underline and highlight 4 variables/methods that I am calling that do not exist.  Above the first 3 I commented the messaging the IDE gives me when I hover.  Yet in the top right corner you can see the Green Check indicating the file passes inspection and is good to go.

So what I want is the inspection to actually not pass and indicate I have 4 potential issues in this file.  In a full project the only way to know to know if any issues like this exist is to go line by line through my entire code base since these issues are not actually reported anywhere.

Comment: Can you please clarify what should be reported by the inspection and why in the code provided? Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho I added more info to my post.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is not reproduced on my side with v2020.2, can you please file an issue at YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue) providing a little sample project and idea.log file (Help | Show Log in Finder). Thanks